# Error path css and javascript

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, opencart

I've have a problem on my site with resource linking

As an example:

**Site address (example) :** *www.abc.com/abc/xyx*

**Sources being loaded :** *www.abc.com/abc/style.css*

**[Link to my website](https://busterspartsonline.com/Sports---Outdoors-Boating---Water-Sports-Boating-Docking---Anchoring-Equipment-Boat-Fenders/G-Series-Fender-Boat-10-20-ft)**

It's load path of css and js wrong.

This is *.htaccess* file

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

 Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder
it does     run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I don't know why it wrong. I build on Opencart.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to the `RewriteBase` value supplied in your `.htaccess` file. This is not required in most cases so remove the `RewriteBase /` from the file and your web server should guess the correct path

If that doesn't solve it, you need to change it to `RewriteBase /abc/xyx/` to match the base of your website. Your files should then access the correct path for css/js